# In Oracle APEX 5.1 On a button-click, how can I run some pl/code, then redirect to another page?

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a button on an apex page. I want to have a dynamic action to call a pl/sql procedure, then redirect to another page in the application.  If I use the redirect built into the button, plus have a dynamic action that executes on the click, it works ok in Chrome, but doesn't work consistently in Firefox--it looks like maybe the redirect is happening in Firefox first, so the pl/sql call on the dynamic action doesn't happen consistently (just guessing here).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you would even need a dynamic action here. You could simply do

- 'Submit Page' action on the button.
- Have a process that executes the PL/SQL code and tag it to the button.
- Add a branch after processing and redirect to the desired page and tag this branch to the button.

Just make sure there are no unconditional branches defined before this conditional branch.

Comment: Just curious, what does 'Submit Page actually do?  I'll try your suggestion.  I haven't used branches before

Comment: When a page is submitted, Apex would automatically store the values entered in the fields or page items, in to the session state which would enable you make further computations, validations and processing on the data. You could also set the branch and tell the application where it needs to land after performing all the actions.

Comment: Learn more about page processing and session state values here : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_pg_procs.htm#HTMDB25145
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_ses_val.htm#HTMDB03011

Answer (score 0):

You can use APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL and put in the URL you want to redirect to:

APEX_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL (
    p_url              in varchar2,
    p_reset_htp_buffer in boolean default true );

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the answer over here:
[Having issues redirecting to another page on closing of modal dialog page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264858/having-issues-redirecting-to-another-page-on-closing-of-modal-dialog-page/)

mixing the onClick of the button with dynamic action isn't good practice because they run simultaneously.
alternatively, you can run your dynamic code on a click of a dummy button, and then use JS to "click" on the real, hidden button

```
$('#HIDDEN_BUTTON_ID').trigger('click')
```